# Using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip Subfolder in zip when its not supposed to be

Tags: c#, compression, zip, sharpziplib

I am using the library `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip`;

My code is follows:

- The path is root. `\\ALAWP\\THIS\\ACORD\\`
- I'm zipping them to the `ZIPDirectory`

However when it's done the file is not named `acord_combined.txt`, instead it's called `ACORD\acord_combined.txt`

What am I doing wrong?

```
public void CleanRoot()
{
    DirectoryInfo RootDi = new DirectoryInfo(FilePrep.RootDirectory);
    string ZipDirectory = FilePrep.RootDirectory + "\\processed\\AceKey"+ DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_H;mm;ss") +".zip";

    ZipOutputStream NewZipOutput = new ZipOutputStream(File.Create(ZipDirectory));

    foreach (FileInfo fi in RootDi.GetFiles("acord*.*"))
    {
        Compress(ref NewZipOutput, fi);
        //MoveFile(fi.FullName,ZipDirectory);
    }

    NewZipOutput.Finish();
    NewZipOutput.Close();
}

public void Compress(ref ZipOutputStream ZipFolder, FileInfo fi)
{
    try
    {
       FileStream fsFileToBeZipped = fi.OpenRead();

       ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(fi.FullName);
       ZipFolder.PutNextEntry(entry);
       int size = 2048;
       byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

       while (true)
       {
          size = fsFileToBeZipped.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

          if (size > 0)
             ZipFolder.Write(buffer, 0, size);
          else
             break;
       }   //end while ( true )

       fsFileToBeZipped.Close();

       //prepare and delete file
       fi.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
       //fi.Delete();
   }   //end try
   catch (Exception e)
   {
        Console.WriteLine("Error zipping File.  Error - " + e.Message);
   }   //end catch
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is right here

```
new ZipEntry(fi.FullName);
```

The argument to zipEntry is the path in the zip file, not the full path the compressed data comes from.  Usually zip libraries, such as 7zip and SharpZip, expose a way to create an "entry path" but the actual data written to the zip is from the full path.

Probably what you want is

```
 new ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(fi.fullName))
```

Comment: Alternatively you could just use fi.Name to get the name and extension of the file.

Comment: Exactly. In general, the first argument is what dictates how the file name shows up in the archive.